# How can I convert RAW image to DICOM image using imebra?

Tags: c++, dicom, imebra

I am new to imebra and want to convert raw image to DICOM image. I have complied the imebra library to my virtual machine (ubuntu 16.04), and followed the tutorial from the website. I found that they do not show how to convert raw image to DICOM image.

Can anyone help me out or tell me the process of converting?

```
#include <imebra/imebra.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;
int main()
{   

    //creat read stream  
    using namespace puntoexe;
    ptr<stream> readStream(new stream);
    readStream->openFile(NSStringToStringW(imagePath), std::ios::in);


    // Create dataset
    streamReader reader =new streamReader(readStream);
    imebra::dataSet testDataSet = imebra::codecs::codecFactory::getCodecFactory()->load(reader);

    // Set Tags
    testSet->setString(0x0010,0,0x0010,0,"testSrt0");
    testSet->setString(0x0010,0,0x0010,1,"testSrt1");

    // Load jpeg
    std::unique_ptr<imebra::DataSet> testSet(imebra::CodeFcactory::load("/home/lixingyu/care.raw"));

    // Save as DICOM
    imebra::CodecFactory::save(testSet, "/home/lixingyu/care.dcm", imebra::codecType_t::dicom);
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I am not quiet sure about the code above. Is there anything wrong with this process??
When I tried this code: `using namespace puntoexe;` an error occurred:

> "error: ‘puntoexe’ is not a namespace-name" and "ptr" was also fault.

Comment: Both `puntoexe` and `ptr` are undefined - so you get a syntax error. You have to include the respective header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a rather old version of Imebra.

With Imebra 4 and 5 you can:

- create an Image object
- fill the image object with raw data
- create a DICOM dataset
- add the image to the DICOM dataset
- fill all the necessary DICOM tags (e.g. sop class, instance, patient name, etc)
- save the DICOM dataset

In code, with Imebra5:

```
include <imebra/imebra.h>

// Create an image 500 pixels wide, 400 pixels height,
// each sample is a 16 bit unsigned value, the colorspace
// is monochrome_2, the higher bit used is 15
imebra::MutableImage image(500, 400, imebra::bitDepth_t::depthU16, "MONOCHROME2", 15);

// We fill the image with data
{
    // We use a writing data handler to write into the image.
    // The data is committed into the image only when the writing
    // data handler goes out of scope.
    imebra::WritingDataHandlerNumeric writeIntoImage(image.getWritingDataHandler());

    for(size_t y(0); y != 400; ++y)
    {
        for(size_t x(0); x != 500; ++x)
        {
            // This method is slow, you can access directly the memory
            // with writeIntoImage.assign() or getMemory()
            writeIntoImage.setUnsignedLong(y * 500 + x, pixelValue);
        }
    }
}

// We specify the transfer syntax and the charset
imebra::charsetsList_t charsets;
charsets.push_back("ISO 2022 IR 6");
imebra::MutableDataSet dataSet("1.2.840.10008.1.2.1", charsets);

// Add the image to the dataset
dataSet.setImage(0, image,  imebra::imageQuality_t::veryHigh);

// Set the patient name
dataSet.setUnicodePatientName(imebra::TagId(imebra::tagId_t::PatientName_0010_0010), imebra::UnicodePatientName(L"Patient^Name", "", ""));

// Save to a file
imebra::CodecFactory::save(dataSet, "dicomFile.dcm", imebra::codecType_t::dicom);
```

Imebra 4 code is similar but the functions returned pointers instead of objects.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of Imebra

Comment: oh,thanks paolo, by the way, what does y * 500 + x mean?  The y * 500 + x should be tagid and it should be total 64 bits.

Comment: is to fill all the pixels in the image: in the example each row contains 500 pixels, so y*500 access each row in the image

Comment: Hi Paolo, I tried your code but an error occured. my environment is ubuntu 16.04 and when I ran my complied file(binary file), "segmentation fault" would occur. When I used gdb to debug mu code, it stoped at imebra::MutableImage image(500, 400, imebra::bitDepth_t::depthU16, "MONOCHROME_2", 15);"
Maybe something wrong with memory allocation??

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include a header file that contains `puntoexe` namespace and `ptr` (probably) inside it.

**EDIT**: On further research it looks like you are using an old tutorial. `puntoexe::ptr` is not used anymore and should be replaced by standard smart pointers.

```
// Load jpeg
std::unique_ptr<imebra::Dataset> 
testDataset(imebra::CodecFactory::load("/path/to/jpegfile.jpg"));

// Save as Dicom
imebra::CodecFactory::save(testDataset, "/path/to/file.dcm", 
imebra::codecType_t::dicom);
```